# com0com silent install (test signed com0com.sys shows up as signed in explorer but not in Device Manager)

Tags: windows-xp, device-driver, windows-2000, driver-signing, com0com

My goal is to have the com0com serial driver install without popping up the install wizard on both WinXP and Win2000.

I am working on WinXP x86. I have followed the [test signing instructions](http://com0com.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/com0com/com0com/Building.txt?revision=1.3&view=markup) for the com0com driver, replacing amd64 with i386 at line 60.

I have added my test certificate as both a root and trustedprovider using the following commands:

```
certmgr /add com0com.cer /r localMachine root
certmgr /add com0com.cer /r localMachine trustedprovider
```

And verified that it is listed under both locations.

I then run the newly built setup.exe. This installs the signed com0com.sys file into C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS and sets up a pair of virtual serial ports and a bus between them. Using explorer, I go to the DRIVERS directory, right click on the com0com.sys file and verify that it has the "test" digital signature. I then go into Device Manager, open the "com0com serial port emulators" entry, pick an entry and do Properties->Driver and see that it says "Not digitally signed". I click details for the driver and can see that it is referring to the com0com.sys driver file that I just confirmed is signed.

I found what might be [a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834656/device-driver-code-signing-for-windows-xp-32-bit) but I'm not sure. Does WinXP demand a WHQL signature? If so, does that explain why the com0com.sys file is signed but the device driver entries say they aren't signed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when talking about drivers, Windows 2000 and Windows XP has only one certain signature in mind -- the WHQL signature. Without putting the com0com driver through the WHQL process, it simply won't be considered signed.

The instructions in Building.txt in relation to signing are talking about a different "constraint" placed by 64-bit editions of Windows Vista and higher -- they simply won't load drivers which are not signed at all -- but that's unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Ok. We'll investigate putting com0com through the WHQL process.